# File 'tesseract.log' is Missing (Python 2.7, Windows)

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to write an OCR script with Python (2.7, Windows OS) to get text from images. First I've downloaded [PyTesser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTesser/) and extracted it to Python27/Lib/site-packages as 'pytesser' and I've installed tesseract with `pip install tesseract` . Then I wrote the following script as self.py:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser.pytesser import *

image_file = 'C:/Users/blabla/test.png'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print text
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blabla/self.py", line 7, in <module>
    text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser\pytesser.py", line 44, in image_file_to_string
    call_tesseract(filename, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser\pytesser.py", line 24, in call_tesseract
    errors.check_for_errors()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser\errors.py", line 10, in check_for_errors
    inf = file(logfile)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract.log'
```

And yes, there's no 'tesseract.log' file anywhere. What should I do? How should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Note: I've changed the line `tesseract_exe_name` from *pytesser.py* from **tesseract** to **C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pytesser/tesseract** but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** Alright, I've just runned *teseract.exe* that is in 'pytesser' and it created the 'tesseract.log' file but I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the line from `def check_for_errors(logfile = "tesseract.log"):` to `def check_for_errors(logfile = "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pytesser/tesseract.log"):` in **../pytesser/errors.py** and it worked.